# How to import jQuery into $ in a Vue.js 3 / Vite application

Tags: jquery, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

I am trying to include jQuery in a Vue.js 3 project, using Vite (https://github.com/vitejs/vite).

I include jQuery in my package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "vue": "^3.0.0-rc.1"
  },
```

I import it in Vite's skeleton's `main.js`, at the first line:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

But this doesn't actually import the jQuery object into `$` (it imports something else).

However, if I change it to:

```
import * as jqueryExports from "jquery";
...
window.$ = jqueryExports.default;
```

Then everything works correctly.

I'm pretty sure this is not the intended way. Also, I suspect that this issue is not Vite-specific, but I haven't tried it with Webpack.

What is the correct way to import jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try like this:

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

or try to simply load it in the header before vuejs

```
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This works in the `main.js` file, but I'm having trouble using it in a TS module file that has an exported class (i.e. using `export class ...`). I get a TS error: `TS1259: Module '....../node_modules/@types/jquery/index" can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag`. But I guess it's progress...

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't simply load the jquery in the header?

Comment: In the tsconfig try setting 'esModuleInterop' to true.

Comment: Nobody wants to load jquery in header script tag cause everybody wants to have only one bootstrap file where all imports are done. Nobody wants to have script tag allaround the application files.